# how to screen mirror my Android galaxy phone on Ubuntu via wifi

Tags: android, screen

how to screen mirror my Android galaxy samsung phone on Ubuntu via wifi
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a free application called [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en_IN). 
It allows you to complete remote access and control of your Android devices from Windows, Mac OS, wireless and without rooting.

Once you install it, you can connect your mobile to the computer using WiFi or USB. Once connected, you need to navigate to https://web.airdroid.com/ and access the device